# how to change id to be the same

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like this:

```
release    release_id
a          1
b          2
c          3
d          4
a          5
f          6
a          7
b          8
```

how to update to let the same release has the same id?
I know update command. But I have no idea how to do this..

Comment: min is OK, I just want it to be unique

Comment: as far as I know, I just can change a value into a static value, like change all the a's release_id to 1,change all the b's release_id to 2,but this problem is dynamic. If there are 10000 releases, I have to run 10000 times command. And my database is very big.

Comment: What are your expected results?

Comment: I wish each release to have a unique release_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update T
set release_id = (
    select min(release_id)
    from T t2
    where t2.release = T.release /* use full name of table here too */
)
```

Comment: good solution! But my computer got stuck dealing with 100000 datas( I have already delete it from 1000000 to 100000)...

Comment: You might have luck by breaking the update into smaller chunks: `where release_id between ...`

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to update from a derived table containing each `release` and its smallest `release_id`. If each release repeats many times, a derived table may be faster than a subquery because the min release_id for each release is retrieved just once.

```
merge into mytable t1
using 
(
    select release, min(release_id) release_id
    from mytable
    group by release
) t2 on (t1.release = t2.release)
when matched then update 
    set t1.release_id = t2.release_id
```

This query can take advantage of a composite index on `(release,release_id)`